# aws route53domains list-domains --region us-east-1 returns empty []

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

Can anyone help me understand why I can't see anything when running the command:

```
$ aws route53domains list-domains --region us-east-1
{
    "Domains": []
}
```

Looking at the console, I can see that I have 5 hosted domains. The problem is that I am fairly sure that 4 of these were created in cdk, but did not successfully delete during updates. Therefore, I want to find the detailed information on them using this cli command so I know which ones I can safely delete.

My undersatnding is that while I am in an ap-southeast region, all hosted domains live in us-east-1. This is supported by the fact that if I issue the command without the region specified or specify any other region, it fails with this error:

```
Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://route53domains.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for `aws route53 list-hosted-zones`. The `route53domains` command is for the domain registration service (similar to GoDaddy). `route53` is the DNS service.

Comment: You're right. I can confirm that `$ aws route53 list-hosted-zones` does the trick! Unfortunately, it doesn't give me the creation time though! :-(  It seems like there is no way to find the creation time of the hosted zone... I guess I can go through the domain records and find the ones that aren't doing anything. Painful, but it'll do I suppose.